# Java GUI Advice

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, parsing

I have a java file which parses an XML file using SAX which seems to work fine.

The following is my SAX.java file:

```
 public class SAX extends DefaultHandler{
     private final List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
     private String tempVal;
     private Student tempStudent;

public void runExample(){
    parseDocument();
    outputList();
}

private void parseDocument(){
    try {
        // get a factory object
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        // get an instance of the parser
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        // parse the XML file and register this
        // class for callbacks
        sp.parse("Students.xml", this);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void outputList(){
    for(Student student : studentList){
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}

// the event handlers....
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // reset
    tempVal = "";
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Student")){
        // create a new Employee object
        tempStudent = new Student();
        tempStudent.setTitle(attributes.getValue("Title"));
    }
 //        System.out.println(
 //                "startElement::qName is "+qName);
}

@Override
public void characters(char []ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException{       
    tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
 //        System.out.println("tempVal is "+tempVal);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localname, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Student")){
        studentList.add(tempStudent);
    } else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Name")){
        tempStudent.setName(tempVal);
    } else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Age")){
        tempStudent.setAge(Integer.parseInt(tempVal));
    } else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("College")){
        tempStudent.setCollege(tempVal);
    } else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("School")) {
        tempStudent.setSchool(tempVal);
    }
}

public static void main(String []args){
    SAX spe = new SAX();
    spe.runExample();
}
}
```

However, I have been asked to present this in a GUI. When a particular radio button is clicked and user clicks parse the XML file will be parsed using SAX and the results will be shown in a text box. I have been given the GUI, it is already coded, my issue is I have limited knowledge of GUI’s and I do not have a clue how to integrate the two of them.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
else if (e.getSource() == parseButton){
        if(saxRadioButton.isSelected()){
            // do SAX stuff
        }
```

I’m just looking for someone to point me in the right direction here. Should I be making the SAX file separately or should I be putting straight into the If statement. I’m completely lost.

Comment: You would call methods in the SAX file from the GUI. Alter it to provide a method to return the parsed content and simply call it from the GUI on action.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thank you for the quick response. I'm still not 100% clear on what to do, but I added the following into the SAX file: 

public List<Student> getList() { return studentList; } 

and then called it in the GUI: 

if(saxRadioButton.isSelected()){ SAX sax = new SAX(); List<Student> studentList = sax.getList(); for(Student student : studentList){ System.out.println(student); } } 

However, it is just printing out empty square brackets ([ ]). I'm sorry for being so slow!

Answer (score 0):

Get the parsed XML from your SAX class and then set it to the required components. It makes sense to separate the gui from your process and will be easier to debug. For example:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(parseButton)){
        if(saxRadioButton.isSelected()) {
            String result = SAX.yourParsingHere();
            yourTextArea.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm still not 100% clear on what to do, but I added the following into the SAX file: 

public List<Student> getList() { return studentList; } 

and then called it in the GUI: 

if(saxRadioButton.isSelected()){ SAX sax = new SAX(); List<Student> studentList = sax.getList(); for(Student student : studentList){ System.out.println(student); } } 

However, it is just printing out empty square brackets ([ ]). I'm sorry for being so slow!

Comment: That probably means the process for adding students to your `List<Student> studentList` is not working correctly.